# Struts Menu Tabs losing focus on IE 11

Tags: css, struts2, velocity

I maintain a J2EE app written with the STRUTS framework.  Recently my company upgraded Internet Explorer and the application now loses focus on the STRUTS Velocity menu tabs in the application.

I am not experienced with STRUTS, but googling is not giving me any options.

In IE8, a user would log into the application and the application tabs would automatically focus on the leftmost tab, and if there are sub tabs, the leftmost sub tab would be in focus.  In IE11, this doesn't happen so the user gets confused when they can't access dialog boxes until they click on the tab.  Clicking on the tab is not an acceptible workaround or using a different browser.

How do I force the leftmost tab in focus in Struts?  Is there an undocumented option for the "Item" element in the config.xml?  Or can I do this with CSS?

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: You can't do two or more things at once either access dialog boxes or click on the tab. Both of them have not any initial context.

Comment: Do you really think anyone can help you with this ? The only thing to check is if you have any error in javascript console, and any non standard code that worked quirkly in IE8 and that has been standardized / dropped in IE11

Comment: No errors.  But I opened the Menu JavaScript in WebStorm and it told me that there were missing semi-colons.  Added them and it works now in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the menu building JavaScript and noticed that the previous developer had missing ";".  I guess IE8 is forgiving with missing ";" than IE11.

Anyhow, problem solved.

Tim